# NodeJS - file does not exist after piping to writeStream and awaiting finish event

Tags: javascript, file, stream

I have the following code in use attempting to download a file over HTTP. I'm attempting to use streams as the file is quite large. The problem I am having is that after I pipe the response to a created WritableStream, sometimes the file isn't created and thus the code will error out later when checking the checksum.

In other words the 'finish' event of the WritableStream is firing even though the file doesn't exist/has not been created.

```
exports.downloadHttpFile = function(url, path, mimeType, checksum) {
    return exports.get(url, mimeType, false).then(function(res) {
        if (res.statusCode != 200) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid response from server when trying to download file'))
        } else {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                console.log('creating file at ' + path)
                const writable = fs.createWriteStream(path);

                writable.once('open', () => res.pipe(writable).once('error', reject)).on('finish', function() {
                    writable.end();
                    try {
                        if (checksum) {
                            console.log(checksum)
                            if (!checksum.hashType || !checksum.hashEncoding || !checksum.hashValue) return reject(new Error('Invalid checksum object'))

                            fs.createReadStream(path)
                                .once('error', function() {
                                    console.log('ERRORS OUT HERE, FILE NO EXIST (path not created by fs.createWriteStream)')
                                })
                                .pipe(require('crypto').createHash(checksum.hashType).setEncoding(checksum.hashEncoding))
                                .once('finish', function() {
                                    const fileHash = this.read();
                                    if (fileHash != checksum.hashValue) {
                                        try {
                                            fs.unlinkSync(path);
                                        } catch (err) {}
                                        return reject(new Error('Downladed file checksum did not match given checksum'));
                                    } else {
                                        return resolve(path);
                                    }
                                }).once('error', reject)
                        } else {
                            return resolve(path);
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log('File did not exist after piping to writable stream..')
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                }).once('error', reject);
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Can someone be so kind as to tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by checking if the file exists and if it doesn't recalling downloadHttpFile. I'm aware this isn't a very good solution and I'm not sure why it's firing the finish event when the file hasn't been created..but it will do for now unless anyone has a better solution.

Code is below:

```
exports.downloadHttpFile = function (url, path, mimeType, checksum) {
  return exports.get(url, mimeType, false).then(function (res) {
    if (res.statusCode != 200) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid response from server when trying to download file'))
    } else {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        const writable = fs.createWriteStream(path)

        writable.on('finish', function () {
          let pathExists = false
          try {
            fs.statSync(path)
            pathExists = true
          } catch (err) {}

          if (pathExists) {
            if (checksum) {
              console.log(checksum)
              if (!checksum.hashType || !checksum.hashEncoding || !checksum.hashValue) return reject(new Error('Invalid checksum object'))

              console.log('creating read stream for path ' + path)
              fs.createReadStream(path)
                .pipe(require('crypto').createHash(checksum.hashType).setEncoding(checksum.hashEncoding).once('error', function (err) {
                  console.log('Error creating crc code')
                  return reject(err)
                }))
                .once('finish', function () {
                  console.log('Finished reading stream')
                  const fileHash = this.read()
                  if (fileHash != checksum.hashValue) {
                    console.log('Checksums did not match')
                    console.log(fileHash)
                    console.log(checksum.hashValue)
                    return reject(new Error('Downladed file checksum did not match given checksum'))
                  } else {
                    console.log('Checksums matched')
                    return resolve(path)
                  }
                }).once('error', reject)
            } else {
              return resolve(path)
            }
          } else {
            console.log('File did not exist.. attempting to redownload' + path)
            return resolve(exports.downloadHttpFile(url, path, mimeType, checksum))
          }
        }).on('error', function (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return reject(err)
        })

        res.pipe(writable).on('error', function (err) {
          console.log('Error reading response')
          return reject(err)
        })
      })
    }
  })
}
```